# Scala - check files from a List[File] what is the last modified

Tags: scala, file

How can I get in Scala, from an List[File], the last modified file?
If there is a way without better-files library it would be perfect! I found only java code to do that. I'm a Scala beginner and I'm trying to do that just with Scala. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `File` is `java.io.File`:

```
val files: List[File] = ???

files.maxBy(_.lastModified)
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you use `java.io.File` to work with a file system.

You should find a file with the greatest modified date. Your code may look like this:

```
files.maxBy(_.lastModified)
```

`lastModified` is method from [java File API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#lastModified())